# Showing a specific location in gMAP

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to show a map in a floating DIV. The thing i want to do is that i want to a specific location with it is first visible. for example: when it is visible i wnat to show banglore city. by default it show some of cities of USA i guess. Is it possible to do so....????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  You just have to set the map's center to the Lat Lng where you wish to initially show.  For instance:

html (your DIV):

```
<div id='map_canvas'></div>
```

google map api v3 JavaScript run when onload:

```
    var initCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(12.970214, 77.56029); //city of bangalor 12.970214, 77.56029
    //create the google map and grabing the DIV
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: initCenter,  //setting the city of bangalor as center point of your map
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/JpBAS/) demo.